# D3.js line chart - positioning the dots

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm having problems positioning my tooltip dots. I'm using an ordinal X scale and i just can't get it to work...not sure if i have to change my data structure or...any insight would be appreciated. I have included a JS FIDDLE link below

```
tooltip_container.selectAll("dot")    
    .data(dataset)         
    .enter().append("circle")                               
    .attr("r", 5) 
    .attr("cx", function(d,i) { /*  return x(d) ?? */})             
    .attr("cy", function(d,i) { /*  return y(d) ?? */})
```

[JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/65dtu8wf/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create the tooltip for all the lines you'll need this

```
tooltip_container.selectAll("dot")    
    .data(dataset)         
    .enter().append("circle")                               
    .attr("r", 5) 
    .attr("cx", function(d,i) {   return x(d.month)  })             
    .attr("cy", function(d,i) {   return y(d.undecided) }) 

tooltip_container.selectAll("dot")    
    .data(dataset)         
    .enter().append("circle")                               
    .attr("r", 5) 
    .attr("cx", function(d,i) {   return x(d.month)  })             
    .attr("cy", function(d,i) {   return y(d.yes) }) 

tooltip_container.selectAll("dot")    
    .data(dataset)         
    .enter().append("circle")                               
    .attr("r", 5) 
    .attr("cx", function(d,i) {   return x(d.month)  })             
    .attr("cy", function(d,i) {   return y(d.no) })
```